# Why do PHP fatal errors display "PHP Warning" prompt?

Tags: php, error-handling

Output from my console:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > my_undefined_function();
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function my_undefined_function() in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in php shell code on line 1
php > throw new \Exception();
PHP Warning:  Uncaught Exception in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in php shell code on line 1
php >
```

Question: **why the `PHP Warning` label in there?**

Calling an undefined function and throwing an uncaught exception are clearly fatal errors, stopping script execution. Uncaught exceptions are explicitly described as such [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) - *the program will terminate with a fatal error*. They are NOT PHP warnings, which don't do that. Why then my PHP displays it like this? I suspect the default error handler may be to blame, but would like to confirm. I am trying to understand the PHP error handling mechanisms in depth, but find this really confusing. My PHP version: 7.2.34. Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, it only seems to happen in interactive mode.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#108006: _“Interactive shell evaluates every expression as you complete it (with ; or }), reports errors without terminating execution, […]”_ – sounds to me like a deliberate feature. (Although that comment is 8 years old, can’t tell how much truth it still holds today.)